# Chopper using MVP Architecture in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mvp, chopper

Im using Chopper for calling api and i want to get result json,
this is the API i want to call 
[https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e1219328d761771cc8b9394]

I would like to ask how to resolve this kind of problem,

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method
>   'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' was called on null.

my class is

```
part 'APIService.chopper.dart';
@ChopperApi(baseUrl:"/b/")
abstract class ApiService extends ChopperService {

  @Get(path: "5e1219328d761771cc8b9394")
  Future<Response> getPost();


  static ApiService create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
        baseUrl: "https://api.jsonbin.io/",
        services: [_$ApiService(),],
        converter: JsonConverter());
    return _$ApiService(client);
  }
}
```

and then I'm calling this function to test the Chooper

```
 void testAPI() async
  {
    final response  = await Provider.of<ApiService>(context).getPost();
    print(response.body);
  }
```

But i having a problem and i cannot call testAPI
can you help me ?

Thank you in advance, sorry for the grammar BTW,

Answer (score 1):

```
void testAPI() async
  {
    final response  = await ApiService.create().getPost();
    print(response.body);
  }
```

This is correct answer for my questions